# Retrofit does not call failure and response.code() is 400

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I'm sure there's something wrong with what I'm doing here. Retrofit does not go to failure even if the code that I'm getting is 400.

```
        AuthenticationService authService = retrofit.create(AuthenticationService.class);
        Call<ValidateTokenResponseMessage> request = authService.validateToken(token);
        request.enqueue(new Callback<ValidateTokenResponseMessage>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ValidateTokenResponseMessage> call, retrofit2.Response<ValidateTokenResponseMessage> response) {
            // When I try to put a breakpoint here I can see that response.code() is 400. 
                ValidateTokenResponseMessage body = response.body();
                if (!body.getValidToken()) {
                    // do success 
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ValidateTokenResponseMessage> call, Throwable t) {
                // do failure
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Callback.onFailure`](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Callback.html) only gets called for exceptions like missing internet connection or invalid https etc.

> Invoked when a network exception occurred talking to the server or when an unexpected exception occurred creating the request or processing the response.

To check for errors you have to use [`Response.isSuccessful()`](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Response.html#isSuccessful--)

> Returns true if code() is in the range [200..300).

Comment: Clear enough. Thanks.